# How to access a property from another class / control, from within a custom class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, class, xaml, toolkit

I'm trying to replicate the messaging system of windows phones, but with another service.
I'm using the Chat Bubble control from the [Coding4Fun Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) to do this.

(Screenshot of the Chat Bubble control):

[image]

The code I came up with below works fine, however the ChatBubbleDirection property within my datatemplate produces an error when it's databound. This is because I don't know how to use a property from another class (if this makes sense?). How would this be done? I just couldn't figure it out...

The XAML property should look like this:

```
ChatBubbleDirection="LowerLeft"
```

As you can guess, this will determine the direction of the little arrow of the ChatBubble.

Here's the code for the message class:

```
using Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.Common;

public class Message : Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.ChatBubble
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string SendingDate { get; set; }
    //public Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.ChatBubble { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the code for the button click event:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LBmessages.ItemsSource = messages;
        Message m = new Message();
        m.SendingDate = "Today";
        m.Text = "This is a message";
        //m.direction = (Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.ChatBubble).ChatBubbleDirectionProperty???
        messages.Add(m);
    }
```

And here's the XAML:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer Height="369" Name="scrollviewer1" Width="500">
            <ListBox Name="LBmessages" Height="250">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="456">
                            <cc:ChatBubble Width="500" Margin="0,0,0,20"  ChatBubbleDirection="{Binding direction}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="430"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding SendingDate}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </cc:ChatBubble>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
       </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
```

Does anybody have any idea what I should write in the Message class? I really don't know how to explain my problem any further. I have tried extending the ChatBubble class within my Message class (as you can see), but with no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message class needs to have a publicly exposed property called Direction, which you will bind to ChatBubbleDirection of ChatBubble.

```
private string direction;

public string Direction
{
    get { return direction; }
    set { direction = value; }
}
```

ChatBubbleDirection can be one of the following

- UpperRight
- UpperLeft
- LowerRight
- LowerLeft

That should work I think.

More info can be found here on [WindowsPhoneGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-Started-with-the-Coding4Fun-Toolkit-ChatBubbleTextBox-Control-for-Windows-Phone).

Comment: Looks like I was over complicating things way too much... A simple string was all it took to get it working! Thanks dude :D

Answer (score 1):

Your Message class extends the ChatBubble class, so it already has the ChatBubbleDirection property from the parent class. All you need to write is:

```
Message m = new Message();
m.ChatBubbleDirection = ChatBubbleDirection.LowerRight;
```

Comment: This didn't work in the binding. +1 for helping anyway! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In class

```
    public ChatBubbleDirection _Direction;

    public ChatBubbleDirection Direction
    {
        get
        {
            return _Direction;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Direction)
            {
                _Direction = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Direction");
            }
        }
    }
```

in main code

```
BBChat.Items.Add(new BMessage()
{
Direction = ChatBubbleDirection.UpperLeft,
}
```